# How to count instances of text

Tags: spss

I have a list of email addresses in SPSS. I'm trying to write syntax to count how many times each email address appears.

For instance:

[image]

In my desired output, if johndoe@aol.com appears in the data 3 times, I want all instances of his email to show a 3 in my new column.

I know I can write syntax to have it count (ie johndoe@aol.com will be assigned 1 the first time, then 2 then 3)... but this is not what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to post your desired output as text, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this:

```
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=EmailAddress /num_instances=N.
```

A new column will appear in the dataset called `num_instances` (you can of course select another name) which will have the desired count appear in all instances of each Email address.

Comment: That's perfect, worked like a charm! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

Steps to do this:

1. Sort cases by email.
2. Get the counts using the Aggregate command.
3. Use the Identify Duplicate Cases command to generate an indicator of whether a given email is the first of its kind in the file.
4. Select cases that aren't the first with that particular email.

All four of those commands are in the Data menu in the GUI.  Syntax to do the whole thing:

```
SORT CASES BY Email.

    *This will create a new variable N_EMAIL with the counts.  It will appear for every case.
    AGGREGATE
      /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
      /PRESORTED
      /BREAK=Email
      /N_EMAIL=N.

*Now we generate a "PrimaryFirst" indicator showing whether a given case is the first instance of its email.
    MATCH FILES
      /FILE=*
      /BY Email
      /FIRST=PrimaryFirst
      /LAST=PrimaryLast.
    DO IF (PrimaryFirst).
    COMPUTE  MatchSequence=1-PrimaryLast.
    ELSE.
    COMPUTE  MatchSequence=MatchSequence+1.
    END IF.
    LEAVE  MatchSequence.
    FORMATS  MatchSequence (f7).
    COMPUTE  InDupGrp=MatchSequence>0.
    SORT CASES InDupGrp(D).
    MATCH FILES
      /FILE=*
      /DROP=PrimaryLast InDupGrp MatchSequence.
    EXECUTE.

*Filter out duplicate cases.
    SELECT IF PrimaryFirst = 1.
    EXECUTE.

*Final cleanup.

    DELETE VARIABLES PrimaryFirst.
```